# stock OHLC data with Date & Time in python

Tags: python, datetime

Team,
I got following python code which is to print and append the 5 minutes OHLC data into mysql DB. I would like to insert the specific Datetime as well into DB, but not sure how to do it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import arrow
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import threading

def get_quote_data(symbol='GOOGL', data_range='5d', data_interval='15m'):
    res = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?range={data_range}&interval={data_interval}'.format(**locals()))
    data = res.json()
    body = data['chart']['result'][0]    
    dt = datetime.datetime
    
    dt = pd.Series(map(lambda x: arrow.get(x).to('US/Central').datetime.replace(tzinfo=None), body['timestamp']), name='Datetime')
    df = dt
    df = pd.DataFrame(body['indicators']['quote'][0], index=dt)
    dg = pd.DataFrame(body['timestamp'])
    #dhl = pd.DataFrame
    df = df.loc[:, ('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')]
    
    df.dropna(inplace=True)     #removing NaN rows
    #df.columns = ['OPEN', 'HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME']    #Renaming columns in pandas
    
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/google_chain')
    df.to_sql(name = 'google_ohlc_data', con =engine, index= False, if_exists = 'append')
    
    return df

data = get_quote_data('GOOGL', '5d', '15m')
print(data)
```

In my SQL DB it only inserts/appends only Open, High, Low, Close and Volume only. I would like to insert Datetime, Open, High, Low, Close and Volume.

Please help.
Thanks,
DR

Comment: You just need to change the `df.to_sql()` line to have `index=True` for the datetime to be added as well.

Comment: Thank you very much , It worked :), Now I have to just split the Date and Time